# Where is the GitHub access token stored, and is there an alternative to access the settings repository?

Tags: intellij-idea

When you want to use the settings repository, you have to supply a GitHub access token. In which file is it stored? And is there an alternative to supplying an access token that does not persist sensitive data, e.g. entering username and password for each IntelliJ session (i.e. from opening to closing IntelliJ)?

(Already asked at [support site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003291419-Where-is-the-GitHub-access-token-stored-and-is-there-an-alternative-to-access-the-settings-repository-), but got no answer.)

Comment: Let me know if you need other clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

The GitHub accounts are stored under

```
%IDEA_HOME%\config\options\github.xml
```

However, the sensistive information such as your access token, or login data, are stored under specific files.
You can customize how IDEA stores them via

[image]

For example, using pre-defined names, you'll find

```
%IDEA_HOME%\config\c.kdbx
%IDEA_HOME%\config\c.pwd
```

`c.kdbx` is a KeePass file.
`c.pwd` is normally Crypt32 encryped file, only on Windows.

> Crypt32.dll is the module that implements many of the Certificate and
> Cryptographic Messaging functions in the CryptoAPI

```
decrypted = createBuiltInOrCrypt32EncryptionSupport(SystemInfo.isWindows)...
...

internal fun createBuiltInOrCrypt32EncryptionSupport(isCrypt32: Boolean): EncryptionSupport {
  return when {
    isCrypt32 -> {
      if (!SystemInfo.isWindows) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Crypt32 encryption is supported only on Windows")
      }

      WindowsCrypt32EncryptionSupport(builtInEncryptionKey)
      ...
```

---

You can check how the platform manages the `c.pwd` file here at [mainKey.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/credential-store/src/keePass/mainKey.kt)
You can check how the platform manages the `c.kdbx` file here at [KeePassCredentialStore.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/credential-store/src/keePass/KeePassCredentialStore.kt)

Ultimately, if you choose *"Do not save, forget passwords after restart"*, everything is going to be in-memory for the current session only.

---

I don't work for JetBrains, so if they want to edit my answer, feel free.

Comment: Thanks. Where is the master password for the password files stored? And is it encrypted, maybe via the Windows account?

Comment: @MarcoEckstein it seems even the master password is saved in those files, not in the OS native storage .

Comment: @MarcoEckstein seems confirmed. Saved in "c.pwd" or "c.kdbx" depending on settings. Here the implementation details for "c.pwd" http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=blob;f=platform/credential-store/src/EncryptionSupport.kt;h=7abdc809d1a1f0716f428ca1e393c6c5d01e5171;hb=ffab894dc05aed94520e06f96c0193151334fa3a